# Create a new column based on row index

Tags: python, indexing

I have a dataframe similar to following,

======================  DATAFRAME ===========================

```
     Question Value 
0    A          1              
1    B          4                
2    C          3                   
3    D          7               
4    E          45  
5    F          78          
6    G          44      
7    H          3           
8    I          4   
9    J          6
```

I want to create a question dimension column based on **index number**, for example for index = 0 to 3, Question dimension='AA', for index=4 to 5, question dimension ='BB'. The rest is 'CC'.

======================  DATAFRAME ===========================

```
     Question Value  Question dimension
0    A          1           AA   
1    B          4           AA   
2    C          3           AA      
3    D          7           AA  
4    E          45          BB
5    F          78          BB
6    G          44          CC
7    H          3           CC
8    I          4           CC
9    J          6           CC
```

How can I achieve this? Thank you in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Use `loc`

```
df.loc[0:3, 'Question dimension'] = 'AA'
df.loc[4:5, 'Question dimension'] = 'BB'
df.loc[6:, 'Question dimension'] = 'CC'
```

```
     Question Value  Question dimension
0    A          1           AA   
1    B          4           AA   
2    C          3           AA      
3    D          7           AA  
4    E          45          BB
5    F          78          BB
6    G          44          CC
7    H          3           CC
8    I          4           CC
9    J          6           CC
```